# Can you identify the caller of an event from outside of a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something mysterious is making a div hidden, and I have no idea what it is.

I was curious if there was a way to bind the div that is being made hidden, to log what is causing it to be hidden.

In this way, I can see where the root of my problem is.

Comment: Try Visual Event http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: Wow very cool. Backbone.js got me started on this scope of thought. Glad there's something else also taking jabs.

Answer (score 0):

Your favourite browser's debugger (javascript developer console, often available via `F12`) will allow you to set breakpoints for event listeners.